# Direct Show Filter using libde265

Tags: c++, video, directshow, live-streaming, decoder

Hey  I am working on a decoder directshow filer. I am using libde265 library for this purpose. But I am facing some issues:

```
HRESULT decoder::Transform(IMediaSample *pIn, IMediaSample *pOut)
{
    FILE * fh;

    tn++;
    long    sizein = 0;
    BYTE    *bufin;
    BYTE *bufout;
    BYTE *central_buffer;
    int counter_tobuff = 0;

    unsigned long   nSrcDataSize;
    unsigned long   nMaxDestSize;
    int totalbytes;
    totalbytes = 0;
    HRESULT         hr;
    // get the input and output buffers 
    pIn->GetPointer(&bufin);
    pOut->GetPointer(&bufout);
    nSrcDataSize = pIn->GetActualDataLength();



    /**************************************de265.cc******************************************************/
    de265_error err;





        /********Intilializing the decoder*******/
        if (tn == 1)
        {

            Init_decoder();

            //de265_start_worker_threads(ctx, 1);
            //de265_set_parameter_bool(ctx, DE265_DECODER_PARAM_DUMP_PPS_HEADERS, false);
        }
        /********Setting the parameters ********/


        /*de265_set_parameter_bool(ctx, DE265_DECODER_PARAM_DUMP_PPS_HEADERS, true);*/






        err = de265_push_data(ctx, bufin,nSrcDataSize, 1, NULL);



        pos += nSrcDataSize;
        if (!de265_isOK(err)) {

        }
        int more = 0;
        const de265_image * img;
        do {
            err = de265_decode(ctx, &more);
            if (err == DE265_OK)
            {
                img = de265_get_next_picture(ctx);

                if (img)
                {


                    set_output_filename("D:\\testnotcreated.yuv");
                    write_picture(img);
                    more = 0;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                memcpy(bufout, bufin, nSrcDataSize);
                more = 0;

            }


        } while (more);
        counter_tobuff = 0;


    /***************************************************************************************************/

        //nMaxDestSize = pOut->GetSize();
    hr = pOut->SetActualDataLength(nSrcDataSize);
    //free(bufin);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {

        //m_pDbg->SendDbg(APP_ID_RGB2YUY2, DBG_ERROR, "CRGB2YUY2::Transform SetActualDataLength failed");
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

What I am assuming is that bufin is continuously receiving the samples and I must pass it to the push_data function and then decode it and write to a file. But it is not happening in that way. 
it is not decoding. Sometime it decode one or two frames.
Although this code is tested in an exe, but the difference is in exe we are reading data from a file and here we are working on continuous stream.
So is there any issue in processing the data, as its a continuous live stream of encoded video.
So what can i do to sort this out so that it decode well and write it in a file.
Any help will be really appreciated because i am stuck.

Comment: libde265 already has a DirectShow decoder integrated into LAV filters, why not simply use theirs?

Answer (score 0):

The decoding order of pictures in H.265 is not the same as the display order. This means that the decoder sometimes has to delay the output of a frame until its display position is reached. Hence, for some frames, it will not output anything and for other frames it will output several (buffered) frames at once. You can use user-data to identify which frame came from which input.